# Did Honeycomb SDK break GridView backward compatibility?

Tags: android, gridview, backwards-compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm working on building a tablet version of an app that will be compatible with 1.6 and up devices and I'm seeing a crash that must be related to an SDK problem.  I'm using the fragment static library to be able to support fragments but still be backward compatible.

If I compile with 2.3 sdk libraries, the app works on both a 2.2 device and a Xoom just fine.  However, if compiled with the 3.0 sdk, the app runs fine on the Xoom, but crashes on pre-honeycomb devices with this exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.AbsListView.setAdapter

What I am doing in the code where it crashes is setting the adapter on a GridView class with a class that extends BaseAdapter.

Anyone else seeing this?

Thanks,
Jess

Comment: How are you setting the adapter? Can you show some code for that and also the stack trace?

Comment: This was fixed in the next SDK update, so I will close this question.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure of the reasoning behind the exception, but the workaround is to cast your view as an AdapterView (the class that defines the method in both honeycomb and pre-honeycomb).

```
AbsListView view = (AbsListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view).setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs for [AbsListView.setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) says it is available since Api level 11 - Android 3.0, so I am not astonished you get this Error on pre Honeycomb devices.

Comment: That's an overridden method that is inherited. All `AdapterView` implementations support `setAdapter()` and have since before Android 1.0